# Link to gemini issue without project parameters

Tags: gemini

Gemini v5.4.2.3872

I would like to link to a gemini issue using just the item #.  But I cannot figure out what the url should be without the project information:

```
http://mygemini/project/Me/30/item/12345
```

Notice that has the project info in it.  What is the correct url for the item:

The follwing do not work:

```
http://mygemini/item/12345
http://mygemini/12345
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put project id of 0 and it works for me:

```
http://mygemini/project/all/0/item/12345
```